# Couldn't get result set as expected with spring jpa query wit in clause

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring jpa query which needs to fetch two records from a table. Here i couldn't get two records while using OR clause.

```
@Query("select i from Table i where i.id.company=?1 AND i.id.employee=?2 OR i.id.employee=?3")
    List<Table> findByCompanyAndEmployee(@Param("company")String company,@Param("employee") String employee, @Param("employee1") String employee1);
```

Later Realized i should not use OR clause so checked with IN clause, But I can still get a single record.from the below query:

```
@Query("select i from Table i where i.id.company=?1 AND i.id.employee IN ?2")
    List<Table> findByCompanyAndEmployee(@Param("company")String company,@Param("employees") List<String> employees);
```

Can someone help me to get the list of records as the result set.

This is the Result Set where i call the method:

```
  List<Table> empList= TableRepo.findByCompanyAndEmployee(SomeCompany, Arrays.asList(Employee1, Employee2));
```

This should return something like :

```
COMPANY     Employee    Duties    EmployeeId
SomeCompany Employee1   1,2,3,4    12345
SomeCompany Employee2   1,3,8,9    23281
```

Table Entity:

```
@EmbeddedId
    private ID id;
    @Column(name="Employee")
    private String Employee;
    @Column(name ="Duties")
    private String Duties;
    @Column(name="EmployeeId")
    private String EmployeeId;
```

And

```
@Embeddable

@Column(name = "COMPANY")
private String company;
```

Comment: Share the input sample and desired output

Comment: Please show us your `@Entity` objects

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

```
      select i from Table i where 
     i.id.company=?1 AND i.id.employee
      IN (? 2, ?3)
```

Comment: When i see the logs in the debug i could see the same thing with the above query but my result set is just giving me only one single record as : 
SomeCompany Employee1   1,2,3,4    12345

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@Query("select i from Table i where i.id.company=:company AND i.id.employee IN (:employee)")
List<Table> findByCompanyAndEmployee(@Param("company")String company,@Param("employees") List<String> employees);
```

Comment: I tried this way too but i still see only single employee details.. :(

Comment: It is highly likely your database contains only one record for the parameters you provided. Could you execute the SQL query with the same parameters directly on your database without jpa and compare the output?

Comment: Yeah, when i checked with the parameters it does worked in the database, but it's not working with the jpa in my present code.

Comment: I can assure you that the jpa query is valid, I can assume you connect to one database from jpa but execute the SQL query on another database when you check it manually

Comment: If i run a query with
`select i from Table i where 
     i.id.company=:company AND i.id.employee=:employee1;` even from service or in the Data Base i could get the records fetched. 
And when i ran this query: 
`select i from Table i where i.id.company=:company ;` I got all the records in the company but when i Ran this query :
`select i from Table i where 
     i.id.company=:company AND i.id.employee IN (employee1,employee2);` I could fetch records from DB but in the service i Get only one record not two records ..